# ProgressDialog not updating progress after activity pause

Tags: android

I am new to android and I made one application in which I am downloading more than one images at a time from firebase. For that, I created one `download()` method and showing the progress dialog. I am updating progress update in `OnCompleteListener`. Everything is working fine but when I put my app in the background by tapping the home button and again resume the app then progressDialog not updating its update and also not `dismiss()` as files are downloaded.

This is my download method in DownloadTask class.

```
List<FileDownloadTask> downloadTaskList = new ArrayList<>();
protected void download() throws IOException, JSONException {
        setDownloadProgressDialoag();
        imageList = image.getImages();
        File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "Images");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdir();
        }
        for (Image image : imageList) {
            String url = image.getImageUrl();
            File imageFile = new File(file, i + "_" + image.getName() + ".jpg");
            if (!imageFile.exists()) {
                downloadRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(url);
                    FileDownloadTask task = downloadRef.getFile(imageFile);
                    downloadTaskList.add(task);
                    task.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                            downloadProgressDialoag.incrementProgressBy(1);
                            downloadTaskList.remove(task);
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                        }
                    });
                    i++;
                }
        }
}
```

This is my progress dialog. Here `downloadProgressDialoag` is defined private in DownloadTask class.

```
private void setDownloadProgressDialoag() {
        downloadProgressDialoag = new ProgressDialog(context, R.style.PackLoaderDialog);
        downloadProgressDialoag.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.downloading));
        downloadProgressDialoag.setMax(stickerPack.noOfSticker);
        downloadProgressDialoag.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        downloadProgressDialoag.setCancelable(false);
        downloadProgressDialoag.show();
}
```

And I am calling this method from main activity when I click Download button

Comment: ProgressDialog is deprecated

Comment: I know that but I don't know that how can I implement it with a progress bar as I am updating it from non-activity class and also how to make progress bar visible from non-activity class. @TimCastelijns